# How to validly reference an object from other class

Tags: java, swing

I have main class, a GUI class, and a CheckingAccount class.
I am supposed to make a Jframe with radioButtons in it to process a CheckingAccount object and should not have the logic in the main!
So I think I could make a CheckingAccount object in the main and get some kind of reference to it, maybe thru a method, or constructor parameter, and use it in the GUI class(use with action listener, and things like that.)
The problem is that for example in GUI class, in the actionPerformed method I can not go like
user.setBlahBlah...//user is a CheckingAccount object in the main.
Can you please help me with this.

Comment: can you include part of the classes you have mentioned and more specific details about your problem with actionPerformed method?

Comment: You can do an CheckingAccount object in the GUI class, so when you create a new GUI object you can alter the current CheckingAccount object from the GUI object. The GUI object must be created from Main class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your GUI class a CheckingAccount variable that is given a reference in a `setCheckingAccount(CheckingAccount checkingAccount)` method or via a constructor parameter. Then you can reference the object inside of the GUI (or better, the Control class if you have one).

```
public class MyGui {
  private CheckingAccount checkingAccount;
  private JButton myButton = new new JButton("My Button");

  public MyGui() {
    myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if (checkingAccount == null) {
          return;
        }
        checkingAccount.someMethod();
      }
    });
  }

  public void setCheckingAccount(CheckingAccount checkingAccount) {
    this.checkingAccount = checkingAccount;
  }

}
```

The main method containing class:

```
public Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CheckingAccount checkingAccount = new CheckingAccount();
    MyGui myGui = new MyGui();
    myGui.setCheckingAccount(checkingAccount);
    myGui.displaySomehow();
  }
}
```

Comment: Via constructor method does not work. I do it like this. In the main new BankGUI(user); In the GUI class: public BankGUI(Object o) then objFromFinal = o; Then I try to do like objFromMian.setSomehting, I get an error saying that it can not find setSomething symbol. SO it comes out I did not reference the object in the main validly... How do I do it then?

Comment: @MikeAnderson: "constructor method" does not exist. Either you're working with a constructor or a method. But yes, you can pass the reference in via a constructor parameter and it would work just the same, as long as you call the GUI constructor after creating and assigning the CheckingAccount object.

Comment: I meant the constructor parameter style, I know that "constructor method" does not exist :) And you can see how I do it above. Anything wrong?

Comment: I'm sure you can not imagine how grateful I am man. Tanks a billion